# Cannot generate multiple divs using jquery append

Tags: jquery

I have to generate random divs on button. For that I have used jQuery `append()` but it does not works properly.

My code:

```
<div class="form-group" id="childPlusSign" >
    <h6 class="formLabel">
        <img src="assets/img/plus.png" class="img-responsive plusSign" alt="plus_sign"> Child
    </h6>
</div>

$("#childPlusSign").click(function(){
$('#childPlusSign').append('
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" name="date[]">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" name="date[]">
        </div>  
    ');
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="form-group" id="childPlusSign" >
    <h6 class="formLabel">
        <img src="assets/img/plus.png" class="img-responsive plusSign" alt="plus_sign"> Child
    </h6>
</div>

    $("#childPlusSign").click(function(){
        $('#childPlusSign').append('\
            < div class= "col-md-6" >\
            <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" name="date[]">\
        </div>\
            <div class="col-md-6">\
                <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" name="date[]">\
        </div>\
                ');
});
```

Comment: to use multi line string you have to add '\' at then end of every lines

Answer (score 0):

The format of the html string you were appending was wrong

```js
$("#childPlusSign").click(function() {

      $('#childPlusSign').append('<div class = "col-md-6" ><input type = "date" class="form-control input-sm" name="date[]" style="background-color:yellow"> </div> <div class = "col-md-6" ><input type = "date" class = "form-control input-sm" name ="date[]" style="background-color:green"></div>');
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="childPlusSign">
  <h6 class="formLabel">
    <img src="assets/img/plus.png" class="img-responsive plusSign" alt="plus_sign"> Child
  </h6>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help.can you tell me how to add styles to appended fields

Comment: check the edits. You can put the style in the string only

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this `

instead of ' in the `append` function because the value you want to append is multiline. Or use ' with one line of code to apppend.

```
$("#childPlusSign").click(function(){
  $('#childPlusSign').append(`
          <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" name="date[]" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" name="date[]" />
          </div>  
      `);
});
```

Comment: thank you for your help.can you tell me how to add styles to appended fields

Comment: No issue. Please do not forget to mark as answer if it fits for you.